# Rechability Issue with framework

Tags: ios

I an have app which has a social login which I've implemented. But when I add the Rechability class in my project it throws errors

```
    ld: warning: ignoring file /Volumes/Backup/Running App/MAHLATI/Mahalati/Mahalati/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration.tbd, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Volumes/Backup/Running App/MAHLATI/Mahalati/Mahalati/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration.tbd
ld: warning: ignoring file /Volumes/Backup/Running App/MAHLATI/Mahalati/Mahalati/SafariServices.framework/SafariServices.tbd, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Volumes/Backup/Running App/MAHLATI/Mahalati/Mahalati/SafariServices.framework/SafariServices.tbd
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SSReadingList", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(please_link_SafariServices.framework_.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress", referenced from:
      +[Reachability reachabilityWithAddress:] in Reachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
      +[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:] in Reachability.o
      -[GSDK_GTMOAuth2SignIn startReachabilityCheck] in GoogleAuthUtilities(GTMOAuth2SignIn.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
      -[Reachability connectionRequired] in Reachability.o
      -[Reachability currentReachabilityStatus] in Reachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[Reachability startNotifier] in Reachability.o
      -[GSDK_GTMOAuth2SignIn startReachabilityCheck] in GoogleAuthUtilities(GTMOAuth2SignIn.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
      -[Reachability startNotifier] in Reachability.o
      -[GSDK_GTMOAuth2SignIn startReachabilityCheck] in GoogleAuthUtilities(GTMOAuth2SignIn.o)
      -[GSDK_GTMOAuth2SignIn stopReachabilityCheck] in GoogleAuthUtilities(GTMOAuth2SignIn.o)
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[Reachability stopNotifier] in Reachability.o
      -[GSDK_GTMOAuth2SignIn stopReachabilityCheck] in GoogleAuthUtilities(GTMOAuth2SignIn.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

i am added **SystemConfiguration.framework** and **SafariServices.frameworks**

I have also deleted **Derived data** but the error is not resolved and I cannot identify the issue.

Tomorrow all things working very well. But from today it will not.

please help me out.

Comment: "i am added SystemConfiguration.framework" well that is the answer, so you must have made a mistake in this area.

Comment: i am adding SystemConfiguration.framework also. but the error is not gone.

Comment: @iosDeveloper I am also getting same error have you solv this? please hel me

Answer (score 1):

Add safariservices.framework , this fixed my issue

Answer (score 1):

You're neglecting to link SystemConfiguration.framework and Security.framework 
from the system.